# Autotools: how to override the intermediate build product directory?

Tags: c++, build, autotools, autoconf

I noticed that many Autotools-based projects generate binaries into `/path/to/project/lib/.lib` folder.

This has a side effect for a cross-platform project where the first built project will contaminate the subsequent builds for other platforms.

I know that I could use `--prefix` and `--exec-prefix` for `configure` to specify **install/deployment** directories, but these have no influence on the `.lib` location.

Is there another switch to specify the immediate build product location so that I can isolate platform-dependent binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create separate build trees for each platform and invoke the configure script from each build tree separately. This will ensure all build artifacts are separated by platform.

Comment: ok, so something like `mkdir -p /path/to/project/build/platformA && cd /path/to/project/build/platformA && ./configure && make ....` ?

Comment: `./configure` will not work,you will need to use an absolute or relative path to your source tree.

Comment: So you mean `mkdir -p /path/to/project/build/platformA && cd /path/to/project/build/platformA && /path/to/project/configure && make ....`?

Comment: That should work, yes. This is documented in the [GNU autotools documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html)